# Como puedo deshabilitar el checkbox contenido en una jtabla?

Tags: java, checkbox, jtable

estoy comenzando con java y me surgió un problema, tengo una tabla que es poblada a través de una base de datos MYSQL estos datos los inserto por medio de la función "addRow()" en donde también agrego un checkbox el problema es que quiero deshabilitar el checkbox para que el usuario no sea capaz de cambiar su estado, sin embargo no he encontrado información acerca de como hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya intentaste con el metodo `isCellEditable()` del `DefaultTableModel`?

Comment: si pero no me funciono, no se si sea por que no lo hice bien.

Answer (score 0):

Mira yo para deshabilitar un componente en jform, por ejemplo hice una funcion en el formulario, enable_checkbox(boolean state)
{
    jCheckBox1.setEnabled(false);
}
fíjate si sirve :) .

Comment: ¿podrias compartirme un ejemplo ? ya que no se como obtener el checkbox de una tabla.